# Printing the first and last 2 elements from a list

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list of dates

`['2021-01-01', '2023-01-02', '2023-02-01', '2024-10-14', 2025-12-31]`

and I would like to print the first and last 2 elements from the list as such :

`'2021-01-01', '2023-01-02' ... '2024-10-14', '2025-12-31'`

What would be the best way to achieve this?

I tried `f"{{'{str(dates[0:2])}' ... '{str(dates[-2:])}'}}"` but it's not what i want

Answer (score 0):

Here is something you are looking for.

```py
dates = ['2021-01-01', '2023-01-02', '2023-02-01', '2024-10-14', '2025-12-31']

first_two = ', '.join(f"'{x}'" for x in dates[:2])
last_two = ', '.join(f"'{x}'" for x in dates[-2:])

print(f"{first_two} ... {last_two}")
```